# Django queryset annotation, charfield with choices and trying to get the display value

Tags: python, django, django-models

The relevant bits of my model:

```
class AnalyticRecord(models.Model):

    APP = "APP"
    WEB = "WEB"
    DASH = "DASH"

    SOURCE_CHOICES = (
        (APP, "Mobile Application"),
        (WEB, "Website"),
        (DASH, "User Dashboard"))

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=SOURCE_CHOICES)
```

I am trying to run an aggregation command. It works just fine like this:

```
data = event.analyticrecord_set.all().values("source").\
    annotate(label=Concat("source", Value(None), output_field=CharField()))
```

However, the problem is the annotation `label` returns "APP", "WEB", "DASH" instead of the actual display value. I know I can use `get_FOO_display()` normally, but how can I pull in the display value into my annotation call? I am looking to get the display values of my `source` field. Thanks!

Comment: The display values aren't stored in the db, so how do you expect it to return them..?

Comment: @thebjorn I was hoping there was some way to run the `get_FOO_display` function or something similar to retrieve the value. I understand that the display values aren't stored in the DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
queryset = event.analyticrecord_set.all().values("source").\
    annotate(label=Concat("source", Value(None), output_field=CharField()))

for query in queryset:
    print(queryset.model(source=query['source']).get_source_display())
```

can you try above code snippet, hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it didn't work as-is. Inside the for-loop, you don't reference `query` only `queryset` so wouldn't whatever result you're expecting to be the same for every iteration? Additionally, what is `s`?

Comment: Edit: changed `s` to `query`

Comment: That did it, thanks, Pramod! I will wait a bit to see if there is a better answer (that can basically do this same thing with less code, inline perhaps). If not, I'll select yours.

Comment: sure, no problem